# Is it possible to remote a Budgie desktop on Focal Fossa 20.04.2 server?

Tags: budgie

I have tried instructions for xrdp and tigervnc and neither have worked. Either I get a black screen and then a disconnect (xrdp) or I receive "some error" or no connection (tigervnc).

Example instructions for xrdp:
https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-20-04-remote-desktop-access-from-windows-10

Example instructions that do work with xfce and SSH tunnel:
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-20-04

What I'm asking is whether the Budgie desktop can be remoted w/o using xfce?

Edit: Yes, following the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54488208/how-to-remote-connect-from-windows-10-to-ubuntu-budgie-18-04-using-default-deskt

Comment: There are a lot of "instructions" out there, of varying quality. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1336989/edit) to be more specific. A link would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while looking for a solution to the instant black screen and session end. I ended up commenting out the last two lines of the file:

```
/etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

Then adding "budgie-desktop" to look like the below:

```
#test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
#exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
budgie-desktop
```

After doing this I was able to connect with Window RDP. Hope this helps someone later.